# Update Inner/Nested RecyclerView from BroadCast Receiver

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, broadcastreceiver

I have a CardViewAdapter that displays a list of folders vertically and then the inner horizontalAdapter displays the contents of the folder horizontally like this:

```
class CardViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private var collectionItems : CollectionItems? = null

    fun setData(collectionItems : CollectionItems) {
        this.collectionItems = collectionItems
        this.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


    fun updateRow(resourceID : String){
        this.collectionItems?.resourceList?.forEach { map ->
            map.value.forEach { resourceWState ->
                if (resourceWState.component?.uuid == resourceID) {
                    val index = (this.collectionItems?.resourceList!!.keys).indexOf(map.key)
                    this.notifyItemChanged(index) // This works but it updates the whole row, not item
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private inner class ViewHolderCard internal constructor(itemView: View, var resource : ResourceWithState? = null, var tabKeyHolder : Int? = null) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        internal var fragmentCallback: FragmentCallback? = null
        internal var horizontalAdapter: ResourcesByCategoryAdapter? = ResourcesByCategoryAdapter()
        internal var mLastClickTime : Long = 0

        init {
            itemView.inner_recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(itemView.context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
            itemView.inner_recyclerview.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
            itemView.inner_recyclerview.layoutManager!!.isItemPrefetchEnabled = true
            itemView.inner_recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)
            itemView.inner_recyclerview.setItemViewCacheSize(20)
            horizontalAdapter?.hasStableIds()
            horizontalAdapter?.courseID = courseID
            itemView.inner_recyclerview.adapter = horizontalAdapter
            fragmentCallback = itemView.context as FragmentCallback

        }

        internal fun bind(position: Int) {
            val dataList = ArrayList(collectionItems!!.resourceList.values)[position]

            tabKeyHolder = tabKey
            resource = ArrayList(collectionItems!!.resourceList.keys)[position]
            val convertToArray : ArrayList<ResourceWithState> = ArrayList()
            dataList.toCollection(convertToArray)
            horizontalAdapter!!.setData(convertToArray)
            horizontalAdapter!!.setCategory(itemView.book_category.text.toString())

            // How to call this?
            fun updateItem(resourceUUID: String){
                horizontalAdapter!!.update(resourceUUID)
            }

        }

    }
```

And this is the simplified CollectionItems class:
[image]

I would like to update the imageView in one of the items inside the folder when the item is downloaded. I already have a broadcast receiver in the fragment that calls the `updateRow` method. This works but I would like to be able to update the item, not the row. How would I access the method `updateItem` in the ViewHolder?

```
// How to call this?
   fun updateItem(resourceUUID: String){
       horizontalAdapter!!.update(resourceUUID)
   }
```

Comment: How do you interact with the inner RecyclerView? Because if you update data with new resourceUUID and invoke notifyItemChanged() the viewHolder should refresh and since you are creating new data for horizontalAdapter everytime you call bind() method it should work

Comment: @PanWrona It does work. I was just trying to find a more efficient way to do it, rather than updating the entire row.

Comment: Well, the RecyclerView data should always be immutable, so even if you update only the horizontal_adapter data and not the CardViewAdapter, you will have different state in each adapter. And it can lead to some weird states, especially when items change a lot